# Problem with linq2sql Group-By then Where

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to get the user records that do NOT have the current role. A user can have multiple roles.

I'm working with 2 tables - Users and UserRoleMap

```
var superAdminRoleId = *GUID*

var query = from user in _userRepository.Table
            join userRoleMap in _userRoleMapRepository.Table
            on user.Id equals userRoleMap.UserId
            // Now, group the roles by the user
            group userRoleMap by user into userRoleMaps
            // get the records that are NOT super admin
            where !userRoleMaps.Any(map=>map.UserId == superAdminRoleId)
            select userRoleMaps.Key;
```

I'm getting the error

> LinqToDB.LinqToDBException: ''map.UserId' cannot be converted to SQL.'

So I revised it to

```
var query = from user in _userRepository.Table
            join userRoleMap in _userRoleMapRepository.Table
            on user.Id equals userRoleMap.UserId
            // Now, group the roles by the user
            group userRoleMap.UserId by user into userRoleMaps   // changed userRoleMap to userRoleMap.UserId 
            // get the records that are NOT super admin
            where !userRoleMaps.Any(map=>map == superAdminRoleId) // update
            select userRoleMaps.Key;
```

Now, I'm getting

> System.ArgumentException: 'Property 'System.Guid Id' is not defined for type 'System.Guid' (Parameter 'property')'

Comment: Try `group ... by user.Id`

Comment: If I do that, it'll return the Id, not the record.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I tried it and game me "Property 'System.Guid Id' is not defined for type 'System.Guid' (Parameter 'property')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a way to fix your `group by`, but looking at what it seems you're trying to accomplish I think you'll get a better-performing and simpler query like this:

```
var userRoleMaps = _userRoleMapRepository.Table;
var nonAdminUsers = _userRepository.Table
    .Where(user => !userRoleMaps
        .Any(map => map.UserId == user.Id && map.RoleId == superAdminRoleId));
```

Comment: This made so much sense that I got out of bed to implement it. Dunno how I didn't think of this. Thanks!